# is it possible to use scrollable (jQuery tools) with just one item?

Tags: jquery, scrollable

I am trying to work out if it is possible to use scrollable, part of jQuery tools, to scroll through 1 item/div vertically.  At the moment I can only get it working with at least two DIVS.  It seems to be set up as an image gallery scroller, but I would like to use it to scroll a playlist vertically and there would be one DIV for the playlist.

If it does have to have at least two DIVs I was wondering if I could set the second DIV to have a height of 1px, or to be hidden?  At the moment it seems like all the DIVs have to have the same height.

Thanks,

Nick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on which plugin you are using. For example jcarousel ( http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ ) you can do it via customizing the options. The options are available here: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Comment: the plugin I am trying to use is 'scrollable', part of jQuery tools here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/

Comment: @Nick: I tried looking but I am unable to figure out how you can accomplish that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Nick, I think what you are asking is how to get the scroll animation to play automatically for one item? If so, I believe you need to set the circular (i.e. loop) parameter to true.

```
e.g. circular: true
```

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.easing.custom = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s = 1.10158;
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1)
            return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.925))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
    }

    var root = 
        $(".scrollable").scrollable({
            easing: 'custom',
            speed: 800,
            circular: true
        }).autoscroll(5400, {
            autoplay: true
        });

    window.api = root.data("scrollable");
});
```